# GET error: Get https://api-int.openshiftX.yyyy.com:22623/config/master

Tags: openshift

I am installing various versions of openshift 4.x but i am getting the above mentioned error..

My bootstrap node comes online and pick the given ip which i gave in dhcp file and i am able to ssh it successfully aswell from my Loadbalancer but whenever i start the master node i get (**GET error: Get https://api-int.openshiftX.yyyy.com:22623/config/master**) sometimes its like **GET error: Get https://api-int.openshiftX.yyyy.com:22623/config/master: EOF**) and also i get this error too sometimes.(**GET error: Get https://api-int.openshiftX.yyyy.com:22623/config/master: x509 :certificate is expired or is not yet valid.** )

Can somebody help me on this.

Comment: Also i forgot to mention that i can ssh to bootstrap node but when i ran journalctl -b -f -u bootkube.service from bootstrap i got the error that tcdctl failed. Retrying in 5 seconds...
Oct 29 09:18:08 bootstrap.openshift5.ustxlab.com bootkube.sh[5452]: Error: error creating container storage: the container name "etcdctl" is already in use by "f189c923adad711163f23d513e3b5341cb82539a7f7b834fe78acb016be2fb35". You have to remove that container to be able to reuse that name.: that name is already in use

Comment: three things: please add this comment to the question as an **edit**, please link to the guide you've used to install these clusters, and please specify the more exact openshift version you're getting this error for